# route groups in laravel

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

In my front end I have a `collection` of `models`. Each `collection` can communicate with the back end and each `model` can also communicate with the back end.

I am trying to devise the proper url routes for it here is what I am thinking

```
create [POST] /mycollection
update [PATCH] /mycollection/22
delete [DELETE] /mycollection/22
```

and for the models

```
create [POST] /mycollection/22
update [PATCH] /mycollection/22/3
delete [DELETE] /mycollection/22/3
```

How should I create my routes in Laravel?

I'm looking into route groups but it's still quite a bit of boiler plate it seems.

```
  Route::group(array('prefix' => 'mycollection'), function()
  {
    Route::get('{id}', function($id){});
    Route::post('/', function(){});
    Route::patch('{id}', function($id){});
    Route::destroy('{id}', function($id){});

    Route::get('{id}/{child_id}', function($id, $child_id){});
    Route::post('{id}', function($id){});
    Route::patch('{id}/{child_id}', function($id, $child_id){});
    Route::destroy('{id}/{child_id}', function($id, $child_id){});
  });
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Is this the right way to do it both RESTful and Laravel?

Comment: You could use http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is RESTful resource routes with Laravel. You can read more [here](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers)

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'mycollection'), function()
{
    Route::resource('/', 'CollectionController@index');
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the first url segment outside, if I can't do this then I can't use resource and will need to manually specify all rest requests and parse the param in each route (post, put, get, delete) ```Route::group(array('prefix' => 'mycollection'), function()
{   $getFirstUrlSegment = '';
    Route::resource('/', $getFirstUrlSegment.'Controller@index');
});```